# OpenOffice - combined roman and arabic numerals page numbers

Tags: openoffice.org

I am putting the final touches on my Master's Thesis, and the format I need to use requires that all pages before the table of contents be numbered with roman numerals, and all following pages be numbered with arabic (regular) numbers.  I can only figure out how to use one or the other, not both in the same document.  thank you for your assistance.

Answer (score 0):

[This OpenOffice page](http://www.taming-openoffice-org.com/newsite/?page_id=81)  contains the information on changing page numbers from latin to arabic numerals and on how to restart page numbering at 1 again. (I understand you already no this bit)

To combine the two types of numbering, you need to make a new page style, choosing the desired numbering format and then applying this new page style to your target pages.

See for detailed information in the index of the help pages under "page styles;creating and applying".

Make sure to add the `pagenumber` field again to the footer in your new page style.